# jquery :not selector not working in next() method

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, tree-traversal

what is the next best thing to use when you want to select the next li item, but not the one that has someClassName. The not selector returns an empty array!

or is this a case off using filter?

```
 <ul class="items">
    <li class="first">pickle</li>
    <li class="someClassName">tomato</li>
    <li>chicken</li>
    <li>cocosnut</li>
  </ul>

var current = $('ul.items li.first');
var next =  current.next(':not(li.someClassName)');
```

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`next` only selects the next sibling of the selected element. You can use `nextAll` method:

```
var next = current.nextAll(':not(.someClassName)').first();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P3EpK/

Note that your markup is not valid.

Comment: I try'd it in firebug and it returns undefined?

Comment: @Richard Yes and you have unclosed `li` tags.

Comment: @Richard Have you checked the fiddle in my answer? If you haven't fixed your markup it should return undefined.

Comment: sorry, lost the browsertab, I still get undefined, I don't get that? I will give the link and you can see yourself with firebug console

Comment: @Richard I can't see undefined value in the console. Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: but I gave you the whole page..haha..it doesn't matter firebug was working against me for some reason, your code worked when I uploaded it, you can try hitting the upper arrow button, thanks @undefined